# Можно ли передать список таблиц из цикла в запрос?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Всем привет.
Запрос

```
SELECT table_game FROM ods_mart.T$PC#SQL_DATA
```

передает обычный список таблиц.
Подскажите , пожалуйста, можно ли передать данный список для следующего запроса?

```
begin
  for i in (SELECT table_game FROM ods_mart.T$PC#SQL_DATA)
    loop
      select * from i.table_game;
    end loop;
end;
```

Скрипт максимально упрощен,в дальнейшем хотел сделать в динамике insert данных в таблицу из талиц,получаемых в цикле.

Comment: только через составление запроса в виде текста (в переменной) и динамическое выполнение этого текста. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#LNPLS629

Comment: можете пожалуйста сказать, в чем может быть проблема?
Ошибка invalid table name.
declare
lvSql   VARCHAR2 (32000);
begin
        lvSql :='ods_mart.t$game#keno';
      execute immediate 'select ticket_game from :1' using lvSql;
end;

Comment: А что такое :1 ? имя таблицы надо явно вписывать в текст запроса, передача его внутрь в виде любых переменных невозможна